# How to stop the playbook if the service is already installed using win_service module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

How to stop the playbook if the service is already installed?

I am trying:

```
- hosts: windows
  tasks:
     - name: check services
      win_service:
          name: serviceName
      register: service_info
      when: service_info.exists
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Next task:

```
- meta: end_play
  when: service_info is not changed
```